# Cognos-how to create a end report for a calendar with aggregation

Tags: cognos

I would like to create an end report, which shows a calendar(month) with aggregation for the specified data.

I am working on cognos 8.4, I have a requirement where I have to show the statistics of the month in a calendar form. The report should be dynamic and it should display the details of the particular month.

Any help or advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a crosstab? I would create an SQL view of your data to get something like this:

select amount, DayNumber, DayofWeek, MonthName, MonthNumber, YearNumber, Weeknumber
from your_view

Within Report Studio filter on YearNumber and MonthName (ordering by Monthnumber). Then create a crosstab where columns would be DayofWeek and rows would be Weeknumber. Inside the crosstab drag the amount field.

Remember Cognos auto-sumarize everything by default unless you override that behavior.

One thing I cannot think to figure it out is how to display the DayOfMonth within the crosstab. That one is tricky since the data is string and it is not groupable in any calculation (MAX, SUM, AVG, etc). If you can find a solution for that, please let me know. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a repeater table, and the table will use a query which gives you the dates, you can apply the filter in that query for the user-selected month.  After you have that part working, you can pull a list into the repeater table and then use master-detail relationship from the date query to the list query, then you can design your list inside the table.